# respond_to do |format| format.js not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller, respond-to

What do I have to enable/install to get my respond_to block to return js?

Rails 4.2.0

ruby 2.2 (Also tried with 4.0... I downgraded to match setup as work...)
The console returns error:

Processing by CameraController#show as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

http://apidock.com/rails/Mime mentions that js is a DEFAULT mime type for Rails.. I tried adding it to the header file but that returned a message in the console saying that I did not need to include it in the header file... What am I missing?

```
#camera_controller.rb
class CameraController < ApplicationController
  # respond_to :js   #I have tried using this...
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js #{render 'show.js.erb'} #I have tried this too..
    end
  end
end

# 'home/sidebar.html.haml'
...
# =link_to "Menu Items", menu_items_index_path, :handlers => [:erb], :formats => [:js], remote:true
=link_to "Camera", camera_show_path, remote: true
...

# 'config/routes.rb'
...
get 'camera/show'
...


# camera/show.js.erb
$("#main_view").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'camera/show')%>")
```

Comment: How did you send the request? What is the url?

Comment: There is no public url. I am running development on my computer. The request is respond_to ..? I am not sure what you are looking for on that one.

Comment: Is your request like `http://www.example.com/XXXX.js`? Request must end with `.js` can respond with `js` template. If not, rails will respond with `format.html`

Comment: The file is show.js.erb

Comment: the url: http://localhost:3000/camera/show

Comment: request: =link_to "Camera", camera_show_path, remote: true

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
=link_to "Camera", camera_show_path, remote: true
```

try using

```
%a{href: "/camera/show.js", class: 'btn', 'data-remote' => true}
```

If that doesn't work, in your camera/show.js.erb add

```
window.location="#{cameras_path}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try when I get home tonight. But I don't understand why I can't format it the way I have it written above. Seeing as how I do that every day at work.

Comment: Sorry. I worked late yesterday.. I tried both with no success. The %a{href... returned the correct pages, but the code was rendered as plain text. The second example returned the error: undefined local variable or method `window' for #<CameraController:0x0000000551b080>

Comment: I updated my question to show my js.erb. It is only one line but I tried .replaceWith, .html, and .raw. They all returned the same result. (code rendered as plain text)